# Play video on Canvas When Image target found. Vuforia - Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm trying to Play a video on canvas using the script play video on canvas in an AR app using Vuforia.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Video;
public class StreamVideo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RawImage rawImage;
    public VideoPlayer videoPlayer;
    public AudioSource audioSource;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(PlayVideo());
    }
    IEnumerator PlayVideo()
    {
        videoPlayer.Prepare();
        WaitForSeconds waitForSeconds = new WaitForSeconds(1);
        while (!videoPlayer.isPrepared)
        {
            yield return waitForSeconds;
            break;
        }
        rawImage.texture = videoPlayer.texture;
        videoPlayer.Play();
        audioSource.Play();
    }
}
```

and this plays video when the play button is pressed. Now I hooked this game object to Default trackable event handler so when tracking is found `rawimage.gameobject.setactive(true);` and (false) when tracking is lost. The main problem here is when I show the camera in front of image target, only a Raw image is being shown and its child **Videoplayer** is not starting. Which results in Video Not being played. Any fix for this?

Comment: would it maybe be an alternative for you to have the videoplayer "play on load" and just disable/enable the entire gameObject holding the videoPlayer?

Comment: @derHugo but the thing is , if this is the case , the videoplayer component will need a object (target texture ) to play the video ..

Comment: So for that I would do this: Take an empty `GameObject`, add the components: `MeshRenderer`, `MeshFilter` and `VideoClip`. The `VideoClip` should now use `Material Override` using the MeshRenderer. Now for the `MeshFilter` choose `Quad` and set its size through the transform Scale (careful it is still in meters). Now create a `Material` and add it to the `MeshRenderer` (Materials -> element 0). Now you should have a Video plane that plays onAwake you can enable/disable as `GameObject`

Comment: No its not working . the empty game object is not visible now . When pressed play , the new game object is not even visible :( .The main reason im playing video on canvas is because , if we use Vuforia's videoplayback with a 3d object , say quad for example , the 3d objects starts shaking in a weird way when image target is found . So i thought if linking it to Canvas so that it stays fixed .

Comment: It always worked for me also as child of a canvas .. unfortunately I can not tell from here what you might have missed

Comment: Here is the link of screenshots https://ibb.co/jgrLhp
https://ibb.co/kuEZ8U

Comment: Did you try to double click it in the hierarchy and look in the Scene View where it is placed? To me it seems very huge and has a big offset ... Is it possible it is simply behind that red overlay?

Comment: no its not behind red overlay , the red screen in play windows is due to my finger . I closed the camera with my finger which made it red . But not its not working . I didnt even hook it up with Defaulttrackableeventhandler script. Its child of canvas and its not hooked up with anything :(

Comment: Can you see it in the Scene view after double click on it?

Comment: give me a mail id or something . Ill record a video of what happens and ill send you .

Comment: This goes against the `no personal data` policy but you could upload it somewhere and post a link here

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=19VBebUEgkoRVUxzdaeHUSUsTYpGw9_wN

Comment: I see you didn't apply a material to `MeshRenderer` -> `Materials` -> `element 0`. Just generate a new Material and drag it in there

Comment: [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dn1Bm69DsNRz-VJTPaJVW9GSBxxwXhpl/view?usp=sharing) Still no use :(

Comment: sorry this seems to be the same video as before with still no material attached (the video plane is still pink .. should be white)

Comment: My bad . [Here is the correct one](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XW1UQuqnrrIySjYUUMCS5HkJIbkBAqpB/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Oh I think I see it now. In the `Canvas` settings do you have `Screen Space - Overlay` or `Screen Space - Camera` selected? The way I did it appears to only work with `Screen Space - Overlay` but not with `Screen Space Camera`

Comment: It's in screenspace - Overlay only :( ... btw if we follow this method and attach to default trackable event handler , will it work ?

Comment: sorry the other way round. `Screen Space - Camera` works for me. Otherwise it might get placed so far way from the camera that it is further than the `Clipping Planes` -> `Far` value of the camera ... maybe it also works for you just increasing this value

Comment: I just made an example you can get [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e5ccem8bl21n4ac/VideoExample.unitypackage?dl=0) (have to import it to any project and open the scene `Assets/VideoExample/Examples`). You can see there a bit clearer what the `ScreenSpace - Overlay` does ... it might be better to just switch to `ScreenSpace - Camera` in general

Comment: Thanks a lot man . It worked like charm even with tracking :)

Comment: Glad to help out. This method might not be the best one to show a video but it always did it for me in the past.

Comment: All that matters is "It works" :) .